# What is the typical usage of boost any library?

Tags: c++, boost

What are the advantages of using boost.any library ? Could you please give me some real life examples ? Why the same functionality couldn't be achieved by having some generic type in the root of object's hierarchy and creating containers with that base type ?

Comment: When I was first learning about Boost's any I found [this article](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403808) by Herb Sutter and Jim Hyslop in Dr. Dobbs. I found it helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I consider that Boost.Variant should always be preferred as it's non-intrusive and still calls for very structured programming.

But i guess the main idea behind boost.any is to provide the equivalent of java and c# object types. It's a way of saying "yes we can" ! :-)

Comment: Boost.Variant cannot replace Boost.Any in case the type to be held is known at run time. For example, see the link referred to in SCFrench's comment: http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403808

Comment: -1. Boost.any can store all types, even primitive ones, not just c#/java "object" equivalents.

Comment: @Macke Don't say C#/java in this case. C# (CLR) can store a primitive value in an object. The languages may look similar, but they do differ.

Answer (score 23):

boost::any will happily store ints and floats, types that clearly have no base classes. A real-life example where you can use it is a virtual machine for a high-level interpreted language. Your "function" objects will need an array of arguments. This can easily be implemented with a `std::list<boost::any>` behind the scenes.

Answer (score 4):

We've used it in a property map, (`std::map<std::string, boost::any>`), to store a lot of things dynamically in a simple, flat dataspace.

Mostly we either stored smart-ptr-to-scriptable-objects or strings, but some entries where other types (floats, vec3f, matrices, and other non-standard objects).

It works pretty well for adding more dynamic capabilities to c++, or wherever you want some type-erasure to just add any type of data to an object.

Answer (score 3):

> Why the same functionality couldn't be achieved by having some generic type in the root of object's hierarchy and creating containers with that base type ?

That calls an object hierarchy -- a construct you are injecting in artificially in to the design for solving a peripheral problem. Further, such a construct is easy to get wrong and a wrong implementation can wreak havoc. `Boost.Any` *is* a community reviewed safe, well-tested alternative.

> Could you please give me some real life examples ?

[TinyJSON](http://blog.beef.de/projects/tinyjson/) uses `boost.Any`.

> What are the advantages of using boost.any library ?

I refer the [introductory](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/any.html) documentation.

Comment: To represent JSON in C++ `boost::variant<T...>` is in my opinion the better choice.

Comment: I did not write that library :-) I am sure you have valid reasons.

Answer (score 2):

We use boost.any as the carrier type for a type-safe tagged variadic container. Here's what that means:

We have a "raft" object, which travels through a set of filters. When a filter wants to add data to the raft, it can do something like this:

```
raft.addTaggedData<ETag1>(3.0);
raft.addTaggedData<ETag2>("a string")`;
std::string str = raft.getTaggedData<ETag2>();
int a = raft.getTaggedData<ETag1>(); // <-- Compile error
```

Where `ETag1` and `ETag2` are members of an enum, and we use a traits template to map tags to types.

The raft class is using a `list` of `pair<ETagType, boost::any>` as a backing store.  Boost.any saved us the pain of managing raw buffers for various types.

Comment: Using a bit of boost.MPL, you could use boost.Variant instead of Boost.Any.

Comment: Even using boost.any was even a bit of a stretch; my team is kind of conservative when it comes to C++ features.  Plus, I haven't learned MPL yet. :)

Comment: @Benoît Boost.Variant would require the raft to know all possible tags (or at least their value types). This might be not possible if for example the raft floats through independent modules which might store a kind of private data in this way. Or even if it is possible it might not be desired due to increased source dependencies implied this way. Although Boost.Any increases run-time costs so it is a trade-off.