# What's the point of C++17's std::any?

Tags: c++, std, c++17

As the title says, I cannot think of any use case of C++17's new "universal type" `std::any`. Is it just a better version of `void*` or is there any other reason to use it but replacing `void*`? Under what circumstances is it good practice to use `std::any` in professional software development?

Comment: A question of checked casting. It's the most general form of type erasure. A subject you should read about.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thank you for this key word. In general: what's the reason for down votes? I am honestly curious about my question. What can I do better? Is it really a silly question?

Comment: I didn't downvote, your question doesn't have any formatting issues and is quite clear. However, this is way too broad for the SO format.

Comment: iterators arent pointers in disguise, they are much more generic and if you want you can still use pointers as iterators

Comment: @tobi303 Thats true, maybe not the best example.

Comment: @StoryTeller I wonder where to ask about design decision in C++ when not on StackOverflow. Any suggestions?

Comment: @M.Winter - Hard to say. The software development related sites on the stack exchange network have specific sections about what is on-topic for them in their respective help centers. The closest I can think of where this won't be off-topic is [softwareengineering.se]. But be sure to consult the help center there before posting, and delete this question to avoid cross-posting spam.

Comment: Well you can always use `void*` in your own small projects, but then it comes to production development, there are too many people involved to know about each others tasks and the code, written by them. So its essential to write code in a safe and supportable way so that another developer can use it as easy as possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781001/what-is-the-typical-usage-of-boost-any-library

Comment: A huge difference is that `std::any` owns its content, while `void*` shouldn't own its pointee. It also takes care of erasing the destructor.

Comment: I sure could find many uses for std::vector<std::any>.  Especially when in a big hurry.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Of course one can use it for quick and dirty solutions ;) I was more interested in more justified use cases.

Comment: A vector<any>  can hold template classes objects.  That's really useful.  A std::map<std::string, std::any> can hold properties and their corresponding tags, program configuration, it can also help to reduce an abstract tree complexity when parsing files. I've used boost::any to keep undo information in MFC Doc/View architecture.  Remember that boost::any does provide type safety, unlike a void*.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Sorry if I was unclear. By this time I already think that `std::vector<std::any>`is very useful. I just meant I can think of ways to abuse `std::any` out of lazyness or hurry. I just do not see the latter cases as justified use cases.

Comment: Of course... But since we've seen people abuse really useful things like `new`, I wouldn't worry much about it.